# Speaker notes beamer - Windows/Linux

Tags: beamer, presentations, notes

I'm making a presentation of thesis in beamer, but I want to include speaker notes.

I see in other publications that I can use \note , but the slides appear side by side in the same screen, and don't split for both screens.

I search a bit about the subject but I can't find a viewer to solve this in Windows and Ubuntu.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!